# Getting error after upgarding scala to version 2.13.6

Tags: scala

I am getting this error after i upgraded scala version to 2.13.6:

> value `++` is not a member of `java.util.LinkedHashMap[K,V]`

Following is the line which is throwing an error:

```scala
 case l => Dsl.map(new LinkedHashMap() ++ l)
```

Comment: Which was your previous **Scala** version that did work? Can you create a **Scastie** to show the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the response.Previously i was using 2.12.10 scala version.Also i  already have  this import statement - 
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

Comment: With `CollectionConverters` you have to add `.asScala` in order to call Scala methods on a Java collection. See the Scaladoc for `CollectionConverters`.

Comment: @SethTisue Could you pls tell where do i add .asScala in the given line                           case l => Dsl.map(new LinkedHashMap() ++ l)    ?

Comment: `new LinkedHashMap().asScala ++ l)` although why not just `l.toMap`?

Comment: @Shalu if you `import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap` then there is no point in doing `asScala`, my advice would be to stop trying random things and rather read the errors and the code and the types carefully. Again, if what you want to do is to convert some **Scala** collection of pairs _(like `List[(Foo, Bar)`)_ into a **Scala** `Map` then all you need to do is call `toMap` in that. - If `l` is not a **Scala** collection, but a **Java** one then `l.asScala.toMap` - `Dsl.map` doesn't expects a **Scala** immutable `Map` then you need to provide more details in order for us to help

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to check the import statements in your file and make sure that you're importing the appropriate Scala collection. The `++` operator is defined on the Scala implementation of `Map`.